# update from google play

Tags: android, google-play

Hi I'm deploying an App free on the google market, so I would like people to be able to share the app directly by bloutooth, but this should be made maintaining the update feature of google play, so they receive updates. Also, would be great if this shared apps are registered as downloads of the app on google play.

any ideas about this topic would be greatly received!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out Android Beam from 4.0.  It's the closest "built-in" implementation of what you're looking for.  The problem with what you're trying to accomplish is that apps don't have access to /data/app, where the apps are stored on the phone.  So, your app would have to download it from some other source (not Google Play).

Comment: thanks for the info, but I guess its not exactly what I'm looking for, once copied I would like to register the app as downloaded from google play, so the user can receive further updates

Comment: As long as the app is installed on the user's phone and has the same signature as the app you published to Play, it will receive updates.

Comment: hoo thanks I was wondering that, because is my first android publication!!